# How To Overcome Eliminate Render-Blocking CSS in PageSpeed Insight

Tags: seo, pagespeed

I performed [PageSpeed Insights](https://developers.google.com/speed/pagespeed/insights/) testing of my website which created by using WordPress.

It displays **Eliminate render-blocking JavaScript and CSS in above-the-fold content**

[image]

The error message disappeared when I remove **style.css** file which is my core CSS file that contains 7000 line of codes.

Referring to the [Optimize CSS Delivery](https://developers.google.com/speed/docs/insights/OptimizeCSSDelivery), I applied this line of coding into my `<script>`

```
<script>
var cb = function() {
    var l = document.createElement('link'); l.rel = 'stylesheet';
    l.href = 'small.css';
    var h = document.getElementsByTagName('head')[0]; h.parentNode.insertBefore(l, h);
  };
  var raf = requestAnimationFrame || mozRequestAnimationFrame ||
      webkitRequestAnimationFrame || msRequestAnimationFrame;
  if (raf) raf(cb);
  else window.addEventListener('load', cb);
</script>
```

Apply this method leads to more blocking resources.

[image]

May I know how to overcome this issue? Thanks.

*P/S: Please provide a reason if you downvote. So I can improve my quality of question next time.*

Comment: People here Downvote just for fun. If you answer a question, and someone disagree's with you, or they have their own answer... they target your answer.

Comment: I'd say PageSpeed Insights is so aggressive in their algorithm, even if your page is loading so fast you may get a low score, for you to achieve a high score you should inline your CSS or place it in the bottom of you page etc, but depending of the size of your site it may cause another issues like FOUC which is a very poor experience for the user, so I also consider to use other tools like: https://www.webpagetest.org/ to check your site performance and don't fight to only get a 100% score in PageSpeed Insights also think in a high quality content and usability as well.

Answer (score 0):

Can you load the CSS asynchonously or are there media queries that are necessary?

The best thing to do is inline some of the media query stuff so that each query is done from the HTML - this will eliminate the render blocking.

I will state however that Pageinsights can be ignored if your page load speeds are showing lower in chrome. It's not 100%. That is where you really want to focus because Google gives you more credit for user feedback than it's bot's quality score. And users WILL bounce less if you can shave it down to 0.5 seconds load.